# INSERT IGNORE does not raise a warning when unique constraint is violated

Tags: mysql

If you use the `IGNORE` keyword, errors that occur while executing the `INSERT` statement are treated as warnings instead. For example, without `IGNORE`, a row that duplicates an existing `UNIQUE` index or `PRIMARY KEY` value in the table causes a duplicate-key error and the statement is aborted. With `IGNORE`, the row still is not inserted, but no error is issued.

Example query:
I have a unique constraint on a table, it is unique on name.

Here is proof of the constraint:

```sql
INSERT INTO table(name, pwd, email) 
VALUES ("sam", "test123", "sam@something.com");

Query OK, 1 row affected (0.10 sec)
```

Again if i try to insert same record  with `IGNORE`:

```sql
INSERT IGNORE INTO table(name, pwd, email)
VALUES ("sam", "test123", "sam@something.com");

Query OK, 0 row affected (0.09 sec)
```

But why it does not raise a warning?

Please could anyone explain reason?

Comment: Please share more details. Why do you expect that any warning is thrown if you use `IGNORE`?

Comment: @NicoHaase thanks for your immediate response. Mysql documentation states that "If you use the IGNORE keyword, errors that occur while executing the INSERT statement are treated as warnings"

Comment: What mysql server version are you using? Can you post the relevant section of your table definition?

Comment: It Does it's just not SHOWN